# Randomly losing trophy points

Tags: clash-royale

I've lost a few trophies without playing a game and thus not losing one. Also this is not the end-of-season reset, which is in about 3 days.

[image]

I've won a game at 4064 points and got 30 points = **4094** trophies. Then after a break I played a 2v2 game, which does not count towards trophies, and another ladder game:

[image]

But instead of 4094 I started at **4047** and won 30 more points, ending up at 4077. This means I lost 47 points without losing a game. Surprisingly, this is the same amount I'd lose with a season reset, but it's still a few days until that happens.

What happened to me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost definitely a glitch. Definitely report it to Supercell. The only possible explanations are:

1. It's a major glitch that physically changes trophy count, and therefore must be fixed immediately
2. It's a visual glitch, that is just a minor bug that causes the trophy count to appear wrong
3. Somehow the season reset happened early

Since you won both games, there is no way your trophy count went down. Maybe there was a balance change, and the leagues were changed up? (didn't see any, but then I haven't logged in for a few days)
(also Wizard lvl 8? you are already dead)

Comment: my first season.. cant lvl everything ;-)

Comment: yeah.. But in leagues you always get paired with people with lvl 11-13 minion hordes , so the wizard can't 1-hit them.

Comment: yup, I know... but as long as I can win a game I'm not really concerned. The topic of the question is a more serious problem.

Comment: yeah, I hope it is resolved.

Comment: contacted Supercell... I'll let you know

Comment: Ok, Supercell support doesn't know where it comes from and suspects a visual glitch. They forwarded it to the devs (or just said so to keep me quiet).